# PDF is not downloading in FPDF

Tags: php, laravel, fpdf

i have a simple form when user submits form i send form data from ajax to controller where my pdf generated code is, but after successful ajax call PDF is not downloading

here is my controller code

```
    $temp=TempInvoice::where('id',$id)->get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.pdf', ['data'=>$temp]);
    $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

and my javascript ajax

```
 var data2=result
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/tyre/api/pdf',
        data: {data:j},
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);

        },
      })
```

can you please help me with this,
(for normal request it works fine but for ajax request it wont work) 
can you please help me with any solution or should i submit form first and then generate pdf?

please let me know any inputs you want from my side,

any tips or comments

Comment: where is your return response? like `return Response::download(.......`

Comment: it was like return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf'); it dosent work

Comment: so i removed the return statement

Comment: Is it compulsory to use post for sending data??

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code with `$pdf->download('invoice.pdf');`

```
return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf')
->header('Content-Type','application/pdf');
```

used `stream` function with `header`

The alternative way (As per my comment used `return`)

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.pdf', ['data'=>$temp]);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Finally: make sure you you configure package properly. [Reference for package configuration](https://codebriefly.com/laravel-5-export-to-pdf-laravel-dompdf/)

Comment: in return i got something like

Comment: %PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj